# How to properly use `__attribute__((format (printf, x, y)))` for C11 U"unicode literals"?

Tags: c, gcc, unicode, c11, unicode-literals

I'm porting an application from using `char*` for everything and everywhere to using UCS4 as it's internal Unicode representation. I use C11's `U"unicode literals"` for defining strings, which expand to arrays of `char32_t`, which are `uint32_t` essentially.

Problem is with properly annotating `printf`-like functions. As "format" is no longer `char*`, compiler refuses to compile it further, as well it won't be happy with `char32_t *` instead of `char *` for `%s` format, I suppose.

I don't depend on stdlib `*printf` family at all, so formatting is done purely by mine implementation.

What is correct solution for this, other than just disable this attribute altogether?

Comment: A side-question: What benefit do you think to gain from using UTF-32 instead of UTF-8? And are you really sure that's worth it? (UTF-32 has multi-codepoint glyphs too.)

Comment: My application operates solely on codepoints, so there is really no point for me to consider grapheme clusters, user-perceived characters and such. UCS4 greatly simplifies string processing as for now, as I can reuse most of existing codebase, and I will migrate internal representation to UTF8 in next iteration.

Comment: I also seem to miss the point of `U"..."` stuff, seems like a complicated step, in particular since C11 adds only minor support to handle these. You could just use the `"\u2002"` notation to implement all Unicode code points that you need as mbs. For the question itself, you should probably ask the gcc people directly. This is nothing very common, so you really need their expertise on the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this in GCC.  It is a known bug, see [GCC bug 64862](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64862)

Comment: Thank you very much for update! Any similar info on clang maybe?